# Color table row based on column value

Tags: javascript

I have an html table and I want to color the rows based on the value in the first column of that row.  If the value is "CONFIRMED" I want to color the row green, and if it is "UNCONFIRMED" I want to color the row red.

The JS I am using to do this is:

```
$(function(){
    $("tr").each(function(){
      var col_val = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
      if (col_val == "CONFIRMED"){
        $(this).addClass('selected');  //the selected class colors the row green//
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('bad');
      }
    });
});
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.selected {
background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}

.bad {
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

The html table is generated from a pandas dataframe in my Django view and passed in like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 15%; overflow:auto;">
  {{ datatable | safe }}
</div>
```

The problem is that it's coloring all of my rows red.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the CSS and HTML?

Comment: eq is 0 based, so you should use `find("td:eq(0)")` to get the first column

Comment: @BenMansley the first column of the table is actually an index.  When I printed `$(this).find("td:eq(1)").text()` to the console it displayed the correct value for each row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you use `==="CONFIRMED"` make sure it's really: UPPERCASE, and that there's no leading or ending spaces `" CONFIRMED"` or `"CONFIRMED "` in the HTML.

The code you're showing will color `.selected` the entire row whos `:eq(1)` TD has the "CONFIRMED" content:

```js
$(function(){
  $("tr").each(function(){
    var col_val = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
    if (col_val == "CONFIRMED"){
      $(this).addClass('selected');  //the selected class colors the row green//
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('bad');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color:green;
}
.bad{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>CONFIRMED</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>UNCONFIRMED</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

nothing bad about it.

if that's not what you see on your screen note that `:eq()` is index based, and elements index start at `0` so `:eq(0)` is probably what you want?

Another probable thing is that **you don't have the exact content string set as `"CONFIRMED"`** but probably there's some spaces before or after - so make sure to trim them using `$.trim()`

```
if( $.trim(col_val) === "CONFIRMED" )
```

if you additionally want to make your code even more flexible about the UPPERCASE or Capitalization you can do as:

```
if( $.trim(col_val.toLowerCase() ) === "confirmed" )
// Will work on "CONFIRMED", "Confirmed", "conFIRMed" etc
```

Comment: Ahh adding `.trim()` fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: what is this ':eq()' ??? this is what i did...but not able to get the result..pls help                                        $("tr").each(function(){
  var status = $('#EnquiryList.status.status').val();
     var col_val = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
      if (col_val == "Offer Generated"){
        $(this).addClass('red');  //the selected class colors the row green//
      } else {
         $(this).addClass('blue');
     }
   });

Comment: my html:       <tr id="enquiryrow${loop.index}" class="enquiryListTableRow teal lighten-4"  style="font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">
       <td style="cursor: pointer" 
        id="checkboxcolumn${loop.index}"><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" 
        id="checkbox${loop.index}"><label class="text-black" for="test5"><%-- ${loop.index+1} --%></label></td>
       <td id="statusEnquiryList" style="cursor: pointer" class="${loop.index}" >${EnquiryList.status.status}</td>
      </tr>

Answer (score 5):

```
<style>
    tr[data-stat="confirmed"]{
        background-color: green;
        color: #fff;
    }
    tr[data-stat="unconfirmed"]{
        background-color: red;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr data-stat="confirmed">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Confirmed</td>
        <td>bla.. bla.. bla..</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-stat="unconfirmed">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Not Confirmed</td>
        <td>bla.. bla.. bla..</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Of the answers given so far, this is cleanest solution. No need for JavaScript or jQuery. Soon the new CSS ":has()" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)  pseudo-selector will be an even more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

To find the first column in a row, you want to use the `first-child` selector. You can iterate over every first column with the `each` function.

We then look at the text and then add the appropriate class to the column's parent (`tr`).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td:first-child").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() === "Confirmed") {
            $(this).parent().addClass("green");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().addClass("red");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cw43ejjf/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the first column in the row you want to use:

```
var col_val = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
```

Change the `td:eq(1)` to `td:eq(0)`