# Change Color of the row based on column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]I have tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32748851/2636829) but not working. Can any one help me to sort out the problem?

```
 <table id="enquiryListTable" class="responsive-table  striped " >
                <thead>
                    <tr class="teal lighten-1 row white-text" style="cursor: pointer"
                        id="tableHeading">
                        <th  id="tableHeadingCheckboxRow"><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                            id="tableHeadingCheckbox"><label class="text-black" for="test5"></label></th>
                        <th  id="tableHeadingName"><div class="col s8 ">Agent / Customer</div><div  class="col s3"><i class="material-icons">swap_vert</i></div></th>
                        <th  id="tableHeadingDateFrom"><div class="col s8 ">Check-in</div><div class="col s3"><i class="material-icons  ">swap_vert</i></div></th>
                        <th   id="tableHeadingDateTo"><div class="col s8 ">Check-out</div><div class="col s3"><i class="material-icons ">swap_vert</i></div></th>
                        <th  id="tableHeadingStatus"><div class="col s8">Status</div><div class="col s3"><i class="material-icons  ">swap_vert</i></div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="display: none;" id=enquiryListTableBody>
                    <c:forEach items="<%=enquiryList%>" var="EnquiryList" varStatus="loop">
                        <tr id="enquiryrow${loop.index}" class="enquiryListTableRow teal lighten-4"  style="font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: normal;">
                            <td style="cursor: pointer" 
                             id="checkboxcolumn${loop.index}"><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" 
                                id="checkbox${loop.index}"><label class="text-black" for="test5"><%-- ${loop.index+1} --%></label></td>
                            <td  style="cursor: pointer" class="${loop.index}" >
                                            <label class="black-text" id="enquiryListAgentNameLabel${loop.index}">${EnquiryList.agent}</label>
                                            <label class="black-text" id="enquiryListAgencyNameLabel${loop.index}">${EnquiryList.agencies.name}</label>
                                            <label class="black-text" id="enquiryListUserNameLabel${loop.index}">${EnquiryList.user.name}</label>
                                            <label class="black-text" id="enquiryListUserEmailLabel${loop.index}">${EnquiryList.user.email}</label>
                                            <label class="black-text" id="enquiryListUserPhoneLabel${loop.index}">${EnquiryList.user.phoneNumber}</label></td>
                            <td  style="cursor: pointer" class="${loop.index}" >${EnquiryList.fromDate}</td>
                            <td  style="cursor: pointer" class="${loop.index}" >${EnquiryList.toDate}</td>
                            <td id="statusEnquiryList" style="cursor: pointer" class="${loop.index}" >${EnquiryList.status.status}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and

```
$("tr").each(function(){
       var col_val = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
          if ($.trim(col_val) == "Offer Generated"){
            $(this).addClass('green');  //the selected class colors the row green//
           } else {
              $(this).addClass('red');
        }
    });
```

I want to color my entire row to green if status is 'Offer Generated'. Any help..i have tried every solution in the stackoverflow.

Comment: In which column is `Offer Generated`? note `eq()` is zero-indexed, here 1 means second column

Comment: which column will be having text as "Offer Generated". I guess it will be in last `<td>`. If so then instead of `.find("td:eq(1)")`; make it `find("td:eq(4)")` as your status column is on 5th number

Comment: not working yet

Comment: is your table dynamic that changed on event/update/append/override

Comment: yes..when i save it will be offer submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Status` is the last column of row. So, to get value of it use `var col_val = $(this).find("td:last").text();`.

**Javascript**

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    var col_val = $(this).find("td:last").text();
    if ($.trim(col_val) == "Offer Generated"){
        $(this).addClass('green');  //the selected class colors the row green//
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }
});
```

Comment: only 1st and 3rd row is green

Comment: Your 1st and 3rd row having status Offer Generated?

Comment: And the status text should be exactly same.

Comment: i will put my screenshot..check my question again

Comment: @Elizabeth In the CSS for red and green class for the color apply !important in the css. May be two class are applying and that's why green color is not implementing.

Comment: i added new css like this .lightgreen{
 color: #DCEDC8;
} and lightred {
 color: #FFCDD2; 
}

Comment: fixed....i removed teal lighten-4 and stripped from my table class..now it worked..thank u :)

Comment: Great to hear it helped you :)